# Dynamics for marketing installation Block

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We're working on Microsoft dynamics 365, currently we're trying to install marketing on a dynamics instance. 
it has blocked since 9 AM. it's blocked on 43%.

[image]

- Is it possible to kill a marketing installation?
- Do you know if a can have some traces?
- is it normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had one problem. It reached the maximum of instance in dynamics.

Now i can say it too long to install it too. i have to wait 48h to install it. if another one have the same issue just wait and control your max instances.